# memory alignment for structs tbb vs atomic_ops

Tags: c++, c, gcc, atomic, tbb

I'm using two different libraries to perform atomic operations. I create a binary tree node structure with a key (8 bytes) and pointer to left and right children (8 each).

The expected node size is 24 bytes.
If I use Intel TBB library I get the expected behaviour. But if I use HP's atomic_ops library I see the node size as 32.

Compilers used:

gcc4.6, gcc4.8, icc 2013

Machine arch: x86_64

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<tbb/atomic.h>
#include<atomic_ops.h>

struct node24
{
    unsigned long key; //size 8
    tbb::atomic<struct node*> child[2]; //size 2*8=16
};

struct node32
{
    unsigned long key; // size 8
    AO_double_t child; // size 16
};

int main()
{
    printf("TBB          node size: %d\n",sizeof(node24));
    printf("HP atomicOps node size: %d\n",sizeof(node32));
}
```

Output

```
$ ./foo.o
TBB          node size: 24
HP atomicOps node size: 32
```

**EDIT**

My assumption is for `node24` the size is rounded up to the nearest 8 and for `node32` the size is rounded up to the nearest 16 (size of AO_double_t). So I added an extra `value` variable (8 bytes) to make the node size as 32. Now I expected the size of `node32` to be 32 but it becomes 48. I don't understand why the extra 16 bytes of padding when it is already aligned at 32.

Comment: I would suspect some alignment issue, try putting key last.

Comment: Tried that. No change.

Comment: try adding a static_assert(sizeof(AO_double_t)==16, "is not 16");

Comment: yes. It passes the static assert.

Comment: So I will assume the problem somehow is in the code `#if ((defined(__x86_64__) && __GNUC__ >= 4) || defined(_WIN64)) \
    && !defined(__ILP32__)
# include <xmmintrin.h>
  typedef __m128 double_ptr_storage;` the __m128 should have align 16.

Comment: Both C and C++ now integrate atomics in the core language(s), no need to use third libraries for that if you have an update platform.

Comment: @JensGustedt That is from C++11 only.

Comment: @Surt, you seem misinformed. C11 has `_Atomic`.

Comment: @JensGustedt, sorry was only talking about C++11 vs. C++03

Answer (score 0):

There is not much reason why non-standard implementations of atomics should agree in their data types they use for it, size and alignment can be different. Depending on compiler flags, one could even use a locked version in some cases where the other uses a native instruction. Just don't mix them.

Modern C and C++ have atomics that are built into the languages, use them if you can. They are even designed to be compatible between the two.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177282/memory-alignment-for-structs-tbb-vs-atomic-ops#comment54163383_33177282), the node32::child is defined using

```
typedef __m128 double_ptr_storage;
```

and it has alignment of 16. Thus the compiler has to put additional padding after the first `key` field since its size is only 8 bytes, another 8 bytes of padded space are needed to fix the alignment. When you added the 3rd field (I assume to the end?) the compiler has to add further padding in order to keep alignment in arrays.